# MinGW won't compile, Error 1

Tags: c++, makefile, mingw

Making a simple hello world app in c++, but it won't compile. I have the folder `C:\WiiGames\e3\` with the files `main.cpp` and `Makefile`. My makefile is:

```
build: main.cpp
    C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe main.cpp -o e3.exe
```

My error is:

```
C:\WiiGames\e3>make build
C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe main.cpp -o e3.exe
make: *** [build] Error 1

C:\WiiGames\e3>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello World!");
}
```

g++ -v:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-4.6.2/configure --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --enable-shared --enable-libgomp --disable-win32-registry --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --build=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.6.2 (GCC)
```

Comment: It would be much easier to answer if you provided your code.

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you run `g++.exe main.cpp -o e3.exe` on the command line directly? If nothing happens, is g++ in your path? I'd start by making sure that g++ is setup and in your path.

Comment: Absolutely nothing. I installed MinGW fresh today.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure it is a tab rather than spaces in the make file before the c:/mingw... Line. It looks like it is make giving the error, not g++.

Comment: It is indeed a tab. running the build command from command line gives no output, so I think its g++.

Comment: Does g++ output anything if you don't pass it a command line? Or just run "g++ -v" to get version info?  Other than the fact that main normally is declared as "int main( int argc, char *argv[])", your code looks fine. It has to be a setup issue with mingw.

Comment: g++ -v added above. If I just run g++ it says: g++: fatal error: no input files compilation terminated. If I build from command line, I get 1 blank line and it exits.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's an old question. These are some solutions i came across (YMMV a lot):

Check if your paths start with `c:/` as opposed to `/c/` or vice-versa.

Check if you're running in the right shell, i.e., one of:

- `c:\msys64\msys2_shell.cmd -mingw32`
- `c:\msys64\mingw32.exe`
- `c:\msys64\usr\bin\bash.exe`

which may differ if used within an IDE.

Comment: Which MSYS2 shell to run depends on which of their compiler flavors you want to use. Running `/usr/bin/bash` directly relies on environment variables being set correctly.