# Netbeans has stopped compiling C++ what did I break?

Tags: c++, netbeans, mingw

I am running on a Windows 7 64 laptop 
And trying to develop C++ with NetBeans.

I really know very little about makefiles or cygwin or this whole ecosystem, so it is a mystery to me.

Least year I installed NetBeans (8.0) it worked fine.

Yesterday I tried to use it but it seems to have stopped working.
Possibly this is because I tried a lot of things to try to get NDK development to work for Eclipse and moved things and or changed critical system variables.

I failed in this but probably messed up my system still farther.

I tried to install the new version of NetBeans (8.1) and I got all sorts of messages about the JDK.

Despite fighting with that for a few hours I was unable to fix these messages however it seems to let me open a simple program and try to compile it but the compile fails yet again.

Since the last time I used NetBeans I also installed, among other things, Visual  C++ 2015 *(at least this worked for the NDK work)*.

Help !

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    return 0;
}
```

When I press the hammer and broom icon (clean and compile) I get these error messages:

> ```
> "/C/MinGW/MSYS/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= 
> SUBPROJECTS= .clean-conf
> make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Andre/Documents/NetBeansProjects/hello compiler'
> rm -f -r build/Debug
> rm -f dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/hello_compiler.exe
> make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Andre/Documents/NetBeansProjects/hello compiler'
> CLEAN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 853ms)
> "/C/MinGW/MSYS/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
> make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Andre/Documents/NetBeansProjects/hello compiler'
> "/C/MinGW/MSYS/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/hello_compiler.exe
> make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Andre/Documents/NetBeansProjects/hello compiler'
> mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
> rm -f "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d"
> g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp
> make.exe[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o] Error 1
> make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Andre/Documents/NetBeansProjects/hello compiler'
> make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
> make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Andre/Documents/NetBeansProjects/hello compiler'
> make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2
> BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 960ms)
> ```

**Does anyone even know how to interpret this output?**

Thanks
Andre'

Comment: Might try reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9961041/10077

Comment: ... and this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13442233/10077

Comment: Try `cd "/c/Users/Andre/Documents/NetBeansProjects/hello compiler"` and then `g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp` . It might give you more output.

Comment: another thing to try would be to not put a space in the filename.  Some build tools can't handle spaces in file/directory names.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by M.M, MinGw doesn't support blanks in path names. Using a path without such should work.